# Passing Gunicorn Systemd File into Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gunicorn, systemd

I can't get the right syntax into my dockerfile to build it with docker-compose.

This my dockerfile :

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN sudo echo

'[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=tahaarmando
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/tahaarmando/Projects/platform
ExecStart=/home/tahaarmando/Projects/platform/flower/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/$

 [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target' 
>>  /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```

When I try to build it I get the following :

```
> Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 5: unknown instruction: '[UNIT]
```

What is the right syntax

Comment: why do you want to do that? You don't run systemd in docker containers you just run the process directly

Comment: I have the same django project in the same directory under many servers, I want to set the systemd file for gunicorn for all my servers just by running the docker container without the need to copy and paste the systemd for each server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no init inside a docker container (by default)

You have to define a Dockerfile that :

1. Install gunicorn
2. Push config file
3. Says to container start a command like `gunicorn [...]`

Details for pushing the config file, inside your dockerfile :

```
COPY /path/to/local/config/file /path/to/file/inside/container
```

Note : Do not use unix sockets with containers, instead, expose ports in order to make your service available to other containers sharing the same network.

Comment: my problem is how to push the config file, how can I echo that text in dockerfile into the gunicorn systemd file